# CImg and Eigen, eigenvalues coming up all the same values

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvector, eigenvalue, cimg

I am using CImg and the Eigen library for a facial recognition project. I have everything (seemingly) working up until the point where i generate the **eigenvalue vector**. Then **all values come up as the same (-6.27744e+066), which is obviously incorrect**. The code is as follows in MSVS 2013 Pro:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CImgList<unsigned char> init_faces;
    CImg<float> avg_face;
    CImgList<float> face_diffs;

    //Code for reading in face images, creating the average image
    //and creating the difference images

    CImg<double> covariance_matrix(face_diffs.size(), face_diffs.size());
    Eigen::MatrixXcd cov_matrix(face_diffs.size(), face_diffs.size());

    //Compute covariance matrix using the pictures that show the 
    //difference from each input from the average
    compute_covariance(face_diffs, covariance_matrix);

    //convert the matrix from a CImg to an Eigen readable matrix
    convert_eigenlib(covariance_matrix, cov_matrix);

    //create EigenSolver object, passing the covariance matrix
    Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXcd> eig_solve(cov_matrix);
    //compute the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix
    Eigen::VectorXcd eig_vals = eig_solve.eigenvalues();

    //This line produces a 25 element long vector of eigenvalues,
    //all of which are: -6.27744e+066
    cout << "Eigenvalues:" << endl << eig_vals << endl;

    return 0;
}

void compute_covariance(CImgList<float> face_diffs, CImg<double> &covariance_matrix)
{
    CImgList<float> transpose;
    float temp = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < face_diffs.size(); i++)
    {
        transpose.insert(face_diffs(i).get_transpose());
    }

    transpose.display();

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < face_diffs.size(); x++)
    {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < face_diffs.size(); y++)
        {
            covariance_matrix(x, y, 0, 0) = transpose(x).dot(face_diffs(y));
        }
    }
}

void convert_eigenlib(CImg<double> covariance_matrix, Eigen::MatrixXcd &cov_matrix)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < covariance_matrix.width(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < covariance_matrix.height(); y++)
        {
            cov_matrix(y, x) = covariance_matrix(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe my issue is contained in one of the 2 user defined functions shown, as every other step gives me the expected outputs.

Comment: Where is the issue, at which line/function? Try posting a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. No one here can guess exactly your problem, and no one will put enough effort into it, unless you make your problem crystal clear.

Comment: Edited to be more concise. Not sure I can give an actual verifiable example without giving the picture library and leaving the code as it was as well, which I'm not sure what method of doing that is acceptable.

Comment: `cov_matrix` is real, so why are you using the ComplexEigenSolver? You should rather use the EigenSolver<MatrixXd> class, and if cov_matrix is symmetrric, then even better to use SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd>. Nonetheless, the problem likely comes for `cov_matrix`. Print it out and import it in octave/matlab to see what you get.